# iframe in revealJS Quarto squished when applying two columns

Tags: css, iframe, r-markdown, quarto, reveal.js

I am generating revealjs slides using quarto and in one of the slides I need to insert an iframe on the left column and some text or a table on the right column. However when I put them together the height of my iframe is shrunk and changing the height argument doesn't help. How do I fix this?

minimal reprex:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  revealjs:
    embed-resources: true
---

```{r}
#| include: false

library(ndtv)
```

## test slide

```{r}
#| include: false

data(short.stergm.sim)

render.d3movie(short.stergm.sim, 
               displaylabels=TRUE,
               launchBrowser = FALSE,
               filename = "test.html",
               d3.options = list(slider = FALSE,
                                 playControls = TRUE,
                                 animateOnLoad = TRUE),
               verbose = FALSE)

```

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}

<iframe src="test.html" width="100%" height="1000%"></iframe>

:::

::: {.column width="50%"}

TEST

:::

::::
````

The resulting output is this:
[image]

What I want instead is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't believe it didn't occur to me, but all that's needed is to use pixels instead of percentage in the iframe options:

```
:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}

<iframe src="test.html" width="500" height="600"></iframe>

:::

::: {.column width="50%"}

TEST

:::

::::
```

And it works:

[image]